# Neovim native LSP for TailwindCSS slow to respond

Tags: neovim, nvim-lspconfig, neovim-plugin

I've been using Neovim with native LSP for TailwindCSS, which is a popular utility-first CSS framework. While the other language servers work fine, I've noticed that the TailwindCSS language server often takes a long time to respond, causing delays in my workflow.

When I say "long time to respond", I mean that there is a noticeable lag between when I make changes to my code and when the editor reflects those changes. This can be particularly frustrating when I'm trying to quickly iterate on my code.

I've tested the TailwindCSS language server in VSCode as well, and haven't noticed any issues with slow response times there. So I'm wondering if there might be something specific to the Neovim integration that's causing the problem.

Has anyone else experienced this issue with Neovim and the TailwindCSS language server? If so, do you have any suggestions for improving the performance?

Comment: Do you perhaps use WSL (2)? I've noticed that LSP performs really bad, when used across "system"-boundaries. I.e. your project is on the Windows NTFS-Filesystem while the lsp runs in the background within WSL.

Comment: btw I use Arch Linux 